# How to unit test authorization globally in CakePHP

Tags: unit-testing, cakephp, permissions, authorization, cakephp-3.0

We're using CakePHP v3.1.x with the [CakeDC Users plugin](https://github.com/cakedc/users).

We're trying to set up our unit tests to help prevent accidentally allowing non-admins to do things they should not be allowed to do. For example, imagine that a developer creates a new admin feature with a new action in a controller. During development she sets the permissions very lax so she doesn't have to log in each time to test it (or something... you get the idea). I'm trying to write a test that will fail if she tries to push this...

Here's my idea for how to do it:

- Create a test that loops over all controllers / actions in the app, and checks to see if a non-admin user is authorized.
- The test has a list of every action that a non-admin user *can* do.
- The test fails if a non-admin is allowed to do anything that's not on the list.

The idea is that every time we intentionally let non-admin users do something, the test fails, and reminds us to go update the list of exceptions. But if we accidentally allow an action without knowing it, the test fails and we fix the mistake. It's a safety catch.

**My question:** Is this the right way to do this? And if so, how can we dynamically generate a list of all of the apps controllers/actions?

Answer (score 0):

> Is this the right way to do this?

**Fix the problem not the symptoms**: Fix your developers behavior of committing "test" and "debug" code or whatever you want to name it. Do peer reviews or have your team leader review the commits. You could try to ask on https://workplace.stackexchange.com/ about how to deal with this situation the best. Check [this question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/59451/loud-and-unprofessional-employee) for an example.

> And if so, how can we dynamically generate a list of all of the apps controllers/actions?

Use this to get a list of folders with controllers:

```
App::path('Controller'); // App
App::path('Controller', 'MyPlugin'); // Some plugin
```

Use [Plugin::loaded()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.2/class-Cake.Core.Plugin.html#_loaded) to get a list of all plugins.

Then use the information to read the controller classes from all the folders. You can then generate test cases (maybe trough a new task of the bake shell?) automatically because you've got a list of controllers from your app and plugin. Use reflections to get a list of public methods from the controllers and filter known public methods like initialize().

Setting up testing auth [is described here](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/testing.html#setting-up-the-request).

If you write a custom test that uses an array structure describing the controllers and actions and their permissions I'm pretty sure that you'll be able to automate it by running over that array structure and using the information to run the auth tests. But honestly, I'm not going to do *that* work here.

Or instead of testing the code directly use [Codeception](http://codeception.com/) acceptance testing. CakePHP [has plugin](https://github.com/cakephp/codeception) for that. This will allow you to test the "real" site by having automated click-through testing. It should be pretty easy to set up a specific users session and then test against URLs for access by expecting a redirect to the login action or whatever you do.